# IBM Integration Bus read a queue from Apache ActiveMQ via SSL

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-integration-bus

I need to read XML messages from a queue (Apache ActiveMQ) from IIB. I have the URL `ssl://...`. Is it possible to achieve this with IIB? We are using IIB 10.0.0.15.

I used a [JMSInput node](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=nodes-jmsinput-node) when I have ActiveMQ configured in my local with the URL like `tcp://...` works fine, but it seems that when I want to replace the URL with `ssl://...` it requires an additional configuration. After a long research I can't figured what is missing or how can I make this node works with SSL.

Comment: Are you receiving any particular errors? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your support Justin, I made some research and now I have almost all set up, the only thing that I´m missing its the keystore, because Im triying to connect to Amazon ActiveMQ Broker that doesn´t have a way to generate the keys.

Comment: I would assume that Amazon uses certificates which are signed by a trusted authority so your client wouldn't need to import the server's certificate into its truststore, but I could be wrong about that.